# Necesito cambiar o actualizar los datos de la sesión en express-session

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, express-session

Estoy haciendo un website con Nodejs y express y necesito actualizar la sesión del usuario que esta en:

```
request.session.user
```

cuando quiero actualizar la información de la sesión y recargarla:

```
request.session.reload((error) => {
   if(error) {
      return console.error(error);
   }
   request.session.user = user;
});
```

debería funcionar pero `request.session.user` sigue con la sesión anterior, ¿alguien sabe? muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estuve mirando leyendo documentación y encontré esto:

Está recargando antes de guardar su cambio. El ahorro generalmente ocurre al final de la solicitud de forma automática. Hay una prueba en session.js que [demuestra ese comportamiento](https://github.com/expressjs/session/blob/master/test/session.js#L258-L284)

El uso `req.session.reload()` revierte los cambios que actualmente se han realizado al procesar la solicitud ...

```
request.session.user = user;
request.session.reload( function (err) {
   request.render('index', { user: req.session.user });
});
```

y si quiere que se actualice la sesión tienes que usar la funcion `save()` asi:

```
request.session.user = user;
request.session.save( (err) => {
   request.session.reload((err) => {
     request.render('index', { user: req.session.user});
   });
});
```